# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I have an error while trying to post for login in postman.. but an error shown cannot read property username,this is my code

This is the Controllers

```
var connection = require('../../config/db');

function Todo() {
    this.create = function (req, res, next) {

        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;

        connection.acquire(function (err, con) {
            con.query('SELECT s.id, s.username, s.sls_nama, s.password, g.id as id_group, g.title FROM salesmen s, groups g WHERE g.id = s.group_id AND username = ?', [username], function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) throw error;
                if (results.length == 0) {
                    // connected!;  
                    if (password == results[0].password) {
                        results[0]['status'] = "Success"
                        res.json(results[0]);
                        res.status(200).send();
                    } else {
                        results[0]['status'] = "Wrong Password"
                        res.json(results[0]);
                        res.status(200).send();
                    }
                } else {
                    res.status(401).json({
                        message: "Wrong password or username"
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

module.exports = new Todo();
```

This is the Routers

```
var login = require('../controllers/login');

module.exports = {
    configure: function(app) {
        app.route('/login').post(login.create);
    }
};
```

[this is the error shown in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaVkD.png)

Comment: Did you check the value of req.body?

Comment: I think you have missed out your alias in where condition "s.group_id AND username = ?" used "s.username = " and try

Comment: Just checking...you installed body-parser, right?

Comment: i have installed the body-parser... @Stan

Comment: "s.group_id AND username = ?" used "s.username = " ... i have try this but still. @SantoshShinde

Comment: how to check it, sir ? im a newbie for node js @JeroenHeier

Answer (score 0):

In your where clause, since you have added alias for your table you must have s.username = ? instead of username = ?.

```
SELECT s.id, s.username, s.sls_nama, s.password, g.id as id_group, g.title FROM salesmen s, groups g WHERE g.id = s.group_id AND s.username = ?
```